# Convert camel-lowercase to camel-upperCase automatically

Tags: java, camelcasing

I'm looking for an easy way to convert all variables and function names from lower_case to upperCase in a java code. There's really a lot of code, refactoring the names one by one isn't a good idea.

It means that this function

```
public void create_table(String table_name)
{
    int useless_var = 0;

    useless_function("string_param");
    // This comment should not be altered, even_if_I_use_some_underscores
}
```

should become

```
public void createTable(String tableName)
{
    int uselessVar = 0;

    uselessFunction("string_param"); // "string_param" must not become "stringParam"
    // Comments should be left untouched, even_if_I_use_some_underscores
}
```

and so on.

I know I can do it with a Python script, but it will take some time and I can easily make a mistake like converting something which is not an identifier. That's why I want to know if there's a tool or something to do this.

Comment: Unless it is an absolute requirement I would not recommend to do this, I would do it while maintaining the application using the refactor tools provided by your IDE. You will, most likely, make mistakes and when changing all the application code at once it will be very hard to test everything. I believe that with time you will be able to make a better job without introducing to many bugs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Java IDEs can cascade the changes you make to one variable where ever it is used.  I believe tools like PMD can find these cases but might not help in fixing them.

If this is a working application, you might want to make corrections as you perform maintenance.  Instead of updating the entire project at once.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try PMD and see what it can do. And yes it's a working application but I need to rewrite a lot of code from it. It would be better if I can convert all this stuff at once, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the refactoring tool in an IDE.

I use Eclipse, where refactoring is right-click on the method or variable, Refactor > Rename.  Type the new name in place of the old name, hit 'return', and it will be renamed everywhere in your code.  Note, it won't work on your string "string_param" though, you'll have to do that manually.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about the refactoring tool, but it will be time-consuming considering the number of functions and variables to rename. I'm looking for something faster.

Comment: @LadaRaider, faster? You can probably let your IDE do this on your entire project: you don't need to do this on a file-to-file basis.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this with [WildEdit](http://www.textpad.com/products/wildedit/index.html).